# How can I add space in the RecyclerView?

Tags: java, android

I need to add some space to start of the first item and to end of the last item of RecyclerView, so they can scroll to edge of the screen (as they can't with RecyclerView's margin or padding)

The problem is spacing between items should be different, so I can't just add this "space" to item layout. Now I'm trying to add ItemDecoration to my Recycler, but thats what happens:

1. Before I even touch it spacing appears letterarily randomly:
   [Random spacing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5tcg3.png)
2. Then, when I scroll to the end and go back, required space appears after last item that fits on the screen, not after the last one of my Recycler.
   [The space right after the last item that fits on the screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oTts8.png)
   [No space for the real last item](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L2cAs.png)

My ItemDecoration class:

```
public class HorizontalItemDecoration extends RecyclerView.ItemDecoration {

private final int horizontalSpaceWidth;

public HorizontalItemDecoration(int horizontalSpaceWidth) {
    this.horizontalSpaceWidth = horizontalSpaceWidth;
}

@Override
public void getItemOffsets(@NonNull Rect outRect, @NonNull View view, RecyclerView parent,
                           @NonNull RecyclerView.State state) {
    if (parent.getChildAdapterPosition(view) == 0)
        outRect.left = horizontalSpaceWidth;
    else if (parent.getChildAdapterPosition(view) == parent.getChildCount() - 1)
        outRect.right = horizontalSpaceWidth;
}
}
```

*horizontalSpaceWidth is 16dp, default spacing betsween items is 4dp.

Comment: It would be helpful if you can include a screenshot of your output!

Comment: Perfect use case for header/footer implementation with recycler view. Here is how you can do it. [code labs](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/kotlin-android-training-headers#0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution by setting LayoutParams to items' parent views. Not the best way I guess, but it works fine for me.

```
RecyclerView.LayoutParams params = new RecyclerView.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    if (position == 0 || position == 14) {
        if (position == 0) params.setMargins(spaceWidth, 0, 0, 0);
        else params.setMargins(0, 0, spaceWidth, 0);
    } else params.setMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);
    holder.background.setLayoutParams(params);
```

*14 is adapter item count - 1

Answer (score 0):

you have to use else for reset the value if position is not 0 or n-1 because views are reusing

```
@Override
public void getItemOffsets(@NonNull Rect outRect, @NonNull View view, RecyclerView parent,
                           @NonNull RecyclerView.State state) {
    if (parent.getChildAdapterPosition(view) == 0)
        outRect.left = horizontalSpaceWidth;
    else if (parent.getChildAdapterPosition(view) == parent.getChildCount() - 1)
        outRect.right = horizontalSpaceWidth;
   else {
       outRect.right = 0;
       outRect.left = 0;
   }
}
```

Comment: Just tried it, nothing changed. I think its because adapter doesn't render items out of screen and counts the last visible item as the very last of RecyclerView. Found the solution by adding LayoutParams, but now with resetting margins for items from pos 1 through N-1 on your advice.